# Watchtower configuration for logging python log in CloudWatch

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-cloudwatch, python-logging, watchtower

I am developing a **REST** service in python which is deployed as **Lambda** on **AWS**.Initially nothing was logged on Cloud Watch CLI so i introduced watchtower.

Below is my logging.in file.

```
[loggers]
keys=root

[handlers]
keys=screen, WatchtowerHandler

[formatters]
keys=logfileformatter

[logger_root]
level=DEBUG
handlers=screen

[logger_xyz]
level=DEBUG
handlers=screen, WatchtowerHandler
qualname=xyz

[formatter_logfileformatter]
format=%(asctime)s %(name)-12s: %(levelname)s %(message)s
class=logging.Formatter

[handler_logfile]
class=handlers.RotatingFileHandler
level=NOTSET
args=('log/xyz.log','a',100000,100)
formatter=logfileformatter

[handler_screen]
class=StreamHandler
args = (sys.stdout)
formatter=logfileformatter

[handler_WatchtowerHandler]
class=watchtower.CloudWatchLogHandler
formatter=formatter
send_interval=1
args= ()
```

the above works fine for logging config files.

```
LOG.info("dev config detected")
```

But not able to log the LOG.info() from any other code in the application. 
specifically REST calls, whereas logging is same everywhere.

Answer (score 1):

You could either use Watchtower or Cloudwatch Handler

**Watchtower**: https://github.com/kislyuk/watchtower

```
import watchtower, logging
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
logger.addHandler(watchtower.CloudWatchLogHandler())
logger.info("Hi")
logger.info(dict(foo="bar", details={}))
```

**Cloudwatch Handler**: https://pypi.org/project/cloudwatch/

```
import logging
from cloudwatch import cloudwatch

#Create the logger
logger = logging.getLogger('my_logger')
#Create the formatter
formatter = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s : %(levelname)s - %(message)s')
# ---- Create the Cloudwatch Handler ----
handler = cloudwatch.CloudwatchHandler('AWS_KEY_ID','AWS_SECRET_KEY','AWS_REGION','AWS_LOG_GROUP','AWS_LOG_STREAM')
#Pass the formater to the handler
handler.setFormatter(formatter)
#Set the level
logger.setLevel(logging.WARNING)
#Add the handler to the logger
logger.addHandler(handler)

#USE IT!
logger.warning("Watch out! Something happened!")
```